# A.InjectFrom<B>(c) in VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, valueinjecter

We have a similar implementation in C# in our project. However, we use VB code in other project and need the same implementation.

A is an object
C is an object
B is a cloneinjection class

Thus

A.InjectFrom<CloneInjection>(C)

Says that CloneInjection is a type but can not be used as an expression. Please help me correct this error as I didnt find much directions from google.

Comment: Try `A.InjectFrom(Of CloneInjection)(C)`.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Lovely, that worked perfectly fine, at least no compile time error. Could you also please help me with a small function converting to VB.NET? I am new to VB :( I don't find much help on certain condition checking equivalent in VB.NET

Comment: Try using http://converter.telerik.com/.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Thank you, I used it, however it says some error in line 1 Typedec1

Comment: What are you trying to convert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `A.InjectFrom(Of CloneInjection)(C)`.